# Where does Webmin stores its passwords?

Tags: linux, unix, passwords, fedora, webmin

I am trying to figure out where does Webmin store its passwords on a fedora machine ? Is it stored hashed ? or plain text and where ?

I have tried to search all the system files and Webmin but no luck !

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Webmin is using `/etc/shadow` file for authentication.

In case Webmin is setup to use password authentication, on **Webmin ⇾ Webmin Configuration: Edit Webmin User** page, it will also store hashed passwords (i.e. in **`/etc/webmin/miniserv.users`** file) based on hashing format defined on **Webmin ⇾ Webmin Configuration: Authentication** page.

Either way, the passwords for authentication stored by Webmin are always hashed!

Comment: That is not really correct. Passwords are not encrypted...

Comment: Thanks, I have completely re-edited my initial answer. It has been a long time!

Answer (score 5):

Both the other answers are wrong, at least if the question is about the users of webmin itself. Default (Webmin 1.710) is to allow only webmin users to log in to webmin, with root as the initial only existing user, and `shadow` authentication for `root` only.

The webmin user database is stored in `/etc/webmin/miniserv.users` with traditional unix style contents.

Answer (score 3):

I think it keeps a **plaintext** copy of the passwords in the `/etc/webmin/virtual-server/plainpass dir.`